# magento : 7405 patch hunk failed error

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-7405

I installing 7405 patch in magento 1.9.1.1.Iam getting error

```
     checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
      Hunk #2 FAILED at 264.
      1 out of 2 hunks FAILED
```

I replaced that file with fresh magento but not working.please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case maybe you  have change this file code.

so follow below steps

copy `app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php`

and paste `app/code/local/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php`

and download new magento fresh package same as your version from magento.

and put fresh file in  `app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php` file

and then apply the patch